# KafkaTopicProvisioner - Failed to create topics

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-azure

KafkaTopicProvisioner - Failed to create topics
2021-04-27T08:48:12.806690772Z org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101

I'm facing the above issue while working with Spring boot, Event hub, and Kafka.
Below is the dependency I'm following.

```
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-eventhub</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the dependency "com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-starter-eventhubs-kafka" instead of kafka-clients, spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka and spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka, which can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-kafka-azure-event-hub